# Default construct tuple of references from variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, variadic-templates, c++20

```
template<typename... T>
struct RoundRobin
{
    // Dangling references
    RoundRobin() : choices{std::forward_as_tuple(T{}...)}
    {}

    // Expected behaviour
    RoundRobin(std::in_place_t, T&... c) : choices{std::forward_as_tuple(c...)}
    {}

    std::tuple<T&...> choices;
};

struct Choice {};

// OK
Choice c1, c2, c3;
RoundRobin good_robin(std::in_place, c1, c2, c3);

// NOT OK
RoundRobin<Choice, Choice, Choice> bad_robin;
```

I would like the provide the ability to both default construct the following struct (as well as inject respective choices).

After default construction, however, the `choices` tuple is initialized with seemingly dangling references and any access attempts result in a segfault.

Is there anyway I can default construct my `choices` tuple (and maintain the existing functionality of reference injection)?

Thanks

Comment: The references in the tuple must reference something. You must store the objects they reference somewhere.

Comment: Would it be ok for `good_robin` and `bad_robin` to have different types? You could adjust the template so that `good_robin` deduces the elements of the tuple to references and that `bad_robin` uses value types in the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to change member tuple to not add reference, and use CTAD:

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct RoundRobin
{
    RoundRobin() : choices{Ts{}...} {}

    // Expected behaviour
    RoundRobin(std::in_place_t, Ts&... c) : choices{std::forward_as_tuple(c...)}
    {}

    std::tuple<Ts...> choices;
};

template <typename... Ts>
RoundRobin(std::in_place_t, Ts&...) -> RoundRobin<Ts&...>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v3sTbWdcr).